# Xamarin facing issue with Telerik package restore

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, telerik

I've been facing an issue with Telerik package version & installed Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin package with our Telerik dll link but still I was get a error like

> The type or namespace name 'Telerik' could not be found in the global
> namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0400)